Parse JSON array into rows and columns in AWS Redshift accessing data through Redshift Spectrum
Had a previous post asking about parsing an array , (JSON data) in AWS Athena into rows and columns which was answered (AWS Athena Parse array of JSON objects to rows) but had a new twist added.
We have made the Athena data available in AWS Redshift using Redshift Spectrum and since spectrum can access glue tables but not views I needed to recreate the query within Redshift.   The data I'm working with comes from a 3rd party where a JSON array is landed into a glue table column typed as array .
When I try to use a query referencing the example (Convert varchar array to rows in redshift)  such using the sql below where 'datalake.temp_table' is a reference to glue table through Redshift spectrum.
with emp_data as
(select empid, JSON_PARSE(json_serialize(properties_textarray)) as dep 
from datalake.temp_table)

select e.*, d
from emp_data e, e.dep d

The error I get is:
SQL Error [500310] [XX000]: Amazon Invalid operation: Spectrum nested query error
Details:
error:  Spectrum nested query error
code:      8001
context:   Expression is not supported by Spectrum.
query:     0
location:  nested_query_rewriter.cpp:738
process:   padbmaster [pid=1073856911]
Is there another way to write this query in Redshift or do I need to land the JSON array into a temp structure in Redshift to work with it?

found a way to parse JSON arrays in Redshift using a Redshift Spectrum data source.  Found a good article https://community.rivery.io/t/unnesting-json-in-amazon-redshift/183 on it.  Finding that Redshift doesn't offer the same level of JSON support as Athena.

Spectrum/athena/glue should be loading the typed column as a super already, u shouldn’t need to reprocess it
